# R package "xgboost" installation fails

Tags: r, xgboost

I try to install the `xgboost` package. But I stumble upon this error

```
* installing *source* package 'xgboost' ...
** libs
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="xgboost.dll" ' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'xgboost'
* removing 'C:/Users/mancph01/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/xgboost'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I try to install this package from github with this command

```
devtools::install_github('dmlc/xgboost',subdir='R-package')
```

Comment: Did you install [Rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)?

Comment: Yes I install rtools.

Comment: To be sure, what is the version of `devtools`?

Comment: I use 1.8.0  version of devtools.

Comment: Did you [set the path](https://stevemosher.wordpress.com/step-six-fixing-your-path/) to Rtools?

Comment: What you mean by se the path of rtools?

Comment: @Pascal if this is simply not following installation instructions and nothing harder, shouldn't we close as offtopic?

Comment: @pythonnovice: R 2.12.1 is [totally ancient (Feb 2011)!!](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-2-12-2-is-available/). Upgrade your R installation to 3.3.x or 3.2.x

Answer (score 3):

"xgboost" is also available on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/). 
So you just need to run `install.packages("xgboost")` takes care of everything :)

Comment: i am using R 2.12.1 and trierd your suggested way of installation but it did not work for me. It says `Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘xgboost’ is not available`. mplease help

Comment: @pythonnovice: R 2.12.1 is [totally ancient (Feb 2011)!!](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-2-12-2-is-available/). Upgrade your R installation to 3.3.x or 3.2.x

Answer (score 3):

- First, your R version (2.12.1) is [totally ancient (Feb 2011)!!](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-2-12-2-is-available/). Upgrade your R installation to 3.3.x (or at least 3.2.x)
- Then, try `install.packages("xgboost")` from CRAN, as @Fitzerbirth showed
- Or if you want to install the latest and greatest source code from `https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost`, follow their instructions at 
  http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html
- If you hit the redirect issue (["package installs fail: Error: Line starting '), then...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131430/cran-bioconductor-package-installs-fail-error-line-starting-doctype-html-p)
- see the other duplicate questions here on SO and also [RStudio support's suggestion on alternative methods to download, e.g. `download.file.method = "libcurl"`](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205370887-install-packages-problem)
- as a fallback I found it faster to just **manually download the package** archive from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/xgboost/ then
  [do a manual install from local zipfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548198/installing-package-from-a-local-zip-file-in-r)
  . http://)

Comment: agree that i need to upgrade . Just so happen that the application that I am using is currently dependent on 2.12, until it is upgraded i will be using 2.12. But this will be helpful, I'll be moving to 3.3 soon. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In general, if you're using an R version older than 18-24 months, expect truckloads of grief. Which application is that that still depends on R 2.12??

Comment: we have home built app which as not updated since 20112

Comment: So update it, already! (use git, and keep separate source trees. Sprinkle in unit-tests, as needed). It'll be less grief in the short run!

Comment: Yes I will. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I had xgboost installation issues but could install an older archived version (‘0.90.0.2’) with

```
packageurl <- "http://cran.r- 
project.org/src/contrib/Archive/xgboost/xgboost_0.90.0.2.tar.gz"

install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```